# How to store and update data from jYearChooser into mysql

Tags: java, mysql, windowbuilder

I am using WindowBuilder to develop an input screen that has a field to select year. I used the jYearChooser for this field and used YEAR as my datatype for the year column in mySQL.
I am however having problem inserting and updating the data from this jYearChooser into mySQL.

Can anybody help please?

Here's my code:

```
String sql =”INSERT INTO counselee (counseleeID, year) VALUES (?,?)”;
PreparedStatement pst = new PreparedStatement();
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,  counseleeIDField.getText());
pst.setDate(2,  convertUtilDateToSqlDate(yearChooserYear.getYear()));
pst.execute();
```

It doesn't give me any error message, it simply doesn't insert data into the year field.

I would also like to know how to use the `UPDATE` statement with the same `jYearChooser` field.
Thanks

Comment: can you update the exception that you are getting ? Is it from sql side or from the code side ?

Comment: Your code for the insertion and the exception, please.

Comment: String sql =”INSERT INTO counselee (counseleeID, year) VALUES (?,?)”;
  
PreparedStatement pst = new PreparedStatement();

pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           
     
   
pst.setString(1,  counseleeIDField.getText());
         
pst.setDate(2,  convertUtilDateToSqlDate(yearChooserYear.getYear()));
pst.execute(); It doesn't give any exception, but does not update the column in the database.